# Free or low cost cross browser testing resources?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I am currently working on a website which needs to be tested across several different browsers, notably Edge, Chrome and Safari. Can anyone recommend a free or low cost platform where tests can be executed across these browsers? It is not required at this time to test mobile so that is out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the list of some Cross Browser Testing resources that may like to check.

(1) [CrossBrowserTesting.com](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/?utm_source=sth&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=crossbrowsertesting)

(2) [LambdaTest](https://www.lambdatest.com/)

(3) [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/)

(4) [Turbo Browser Sandbox](https://turbo.net/browsers)

Below are some site lists which shows the information about Cross Browser Testing resources:

[Top 10 Cross Browser Testing Tools in 2019 (Latest Ranking)](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/best-cross-browser-testing-tools-to-ease-your-browser-compatibility-testing-efforts/)

[10 Best Cross Browser Compatibility Testing Tools in 2019](https://www.guru99.com/top-10-cross-browser-testing-tools.html)

[5 cross-browser testing tools to try today](https://www.creativebloq.com/features/5-cross-browser-testing-tools-to-try-today)

You can try to check and compare them and try to find the best suitable tool for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT

Comment: Another option to add to the list: https://testingbot.com - over 1800 browser and device combinations for testing.